# Random Menu Reordering

Tags: joomla-2.5

Has anyone experienced Menus reordering themselves in Joomla 2.5 ?
I have had that happen several times and it seems unlikely it's a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was a bug when migrating from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5. Whether this is the case for you or not, try the following:

1. Login to PhpMyAdmin
2. Select the database that is associated with your Joomla site
3. Click on the **SQL** tab
4. Copy the following database query (change xxx to your own database prefix)

   ```
   UPDATE XXX_menu SET ordering = 0
   ```

This should reset the ordering for you.

**Note:** Once done, make sure you have the latest version of the Joomla 2.5 series (**2.5.28**)

Hope this helps